# copy specific rows to another sheet just if row contains a value

Tags: excel, vba, rows, copy-paste

I want to copy a specific columns based on column A value.

Precisely, I want to copy columns A, C and D of sheet `A` to B, C and D of sheet `B`. But just the party where column A of sheet `A` contains `AAAAA`.

This example is just to simplify, in reality I have hundreds of rows so I need a necessary a loop and in sheet `B` I want to paste under the header:

How my Excel sheet looks:
[[image: How my excel sheet looks]][1

```
Sub COOPPYY()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, s As String
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim trg As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim c As Range

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A")
    Set trg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("B")

    'For i = 1 To N
    'j = 1

    src.Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=trg.Range("B:B")
    src.Range("C:C").Copy Destination:=trg.Range("D:D")

    src.Range("D:D").Copy Destination:=trg.Range("C:C")
End Sub
```

How the second sheet looks where I want to copy:
[image: how the second sheet looks where i want to copy]

Comment: Please note that writing in ALL CAPS is considered as shouting here and therefore very unfriendly.

Comment: Oups .. i'm really sorry i didn't mean it at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub CopyIt()

    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, s As String
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim trg As Worksheet

    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A")
    Set trg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("B")

    N = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    j = trg.cells(rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For i = 1 To N
        With src.Rows(i)             
            If .cells(1).Value = "AAAAA" Then
                .cells(1).Copy trg.cells(j, "B")
                .cells(3).Resize(1,2).copy trg.cells(j, "C")
                j = j + 1 
            End If
         End With 
     Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you a lot that give me an idea, but what i get using this code : is just columns "C" and "D" copied .. I want to copy column "A" too .. and i don,t know how to do it

Comment: Sorry bad copy-paste fixed that second line.